# RadGrid contains filter on integer column while preserving integer sorting functionability

Tags: sorting, filtering, radgrid

I have a RadGrid with a numbers column that is filterable and sortable. While the column's datatype is set to integer, there is no filtering function for contains. It is just set for 'exact'. The way I figured out how to get around this is to change the column's datatype to a string. The filtering then functions perfectly.

The sorting, however, breaks. If the numbers have different lengths, it raises an issue.

Here's a quick example: You have three numbers: 100, 70, 400.

Sorting ascending as per integer column: 70, 100, 400.
Sorting ascending as per string column: 100, 400, 70.

Is there a way for me to have the filtering capabilities of a string column while preserving the sorting of the integer column? In other words, alphanumeric sorting versus alpha or numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, turns out that there is no way to do this with one column.

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Item" DataType="System.String"
    HeaderText="Item" SortExpression="Item1"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

This is the method I am currently using. This will make another column with the same data but is type string. This will be sorted based off of the integer column instead of itself though. This allows the use of string filtering and integer sorting.